# How to convert points from MySql database to WKT using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, wkt

In MySql database I have points (pairs of latitudes and longitudes represented as doubles) like this:

```
LATITUDE | LONGITUDE
---------|----------
45.045664| 46.084528
26.938933| 60.903848
       .....
```

Now, what I need is to get these points from my database (which is not a problem at all) and echo them in a WKT format (this part I don't know). This PHP script is going to be a part of an API used by Windows App.

So question is: how can I convert points to WKT format? Is there any plugin I can use? Which are the best approaches?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Output should look like WKT line, e.g.:

```
LINESTRING(3 4,10 50,20 25)
```

Comment: I think you should show us a sample of what your WKT expected output is.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql has its own GIS conversion functions to convert data stored in its internal geometry datatypes to textual representation, such as WKT.

Specifically, use [ST_AsWKT(g) or ST_AsText(g)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-format-conversion-functions.html#function_st-astext) functions to convert data to WKT format:

> Converts a value in internal geometry format to its WKT representation
>   and returns the string result.
>
> ```
> mysql> SET @g = 'LineString(1 1,2 2,3 3)'; mysql> SELECT
> ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromText(@g));
> +--------------------------------+ | ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromText(@g)) |
> +--------------------------------+ | LINESTRING(1 1,2 2,3 3)        |
> +--------------------------------+
> ```
>
> ST_AsText(), ST_AsWKT(), AsText(), and AsWKT() are synonyms.